# Get the Response from POST request

Tags: java, post, inputstream, outputstream, httpsurlconnection

I would like to obtain the response from a `HttpsURLConnection` POST request.
If I try to do the request with `PostMan`, I have one message as response `(es: 1520)`. I have to save this code, but I find the method for read just the `getResponseCode()` (200) or `getResponseMessage()` ("OK"). I should use another libraries? Because in the `HttpsUrlConnection` method I don't find anything useful (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

My code is:

```
  HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

  con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
  con.setDoOutput(true);
  con.setUseCaches(false);
  con.setRequestMethod("POST");
  con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
  con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", w_AECONTYP);
  con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", w_AEACCCHA);
  con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", w_AEACCENC);

 StringBuilder postFile = new StringBuilder();
  byte[] postFileBytes =w_FileToSend.getBytes("UTF-8");
  con.setDoOutput(true);
  try {
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(postFileBytes);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Connection Failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
  // get 200 code "OK"

      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

  String inputLine;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  response.append(inputLine);
  }

  in.close();
```

But when arrived at the **WHILE** loop, it doesn't enter in the cycle.
How I can do this? 
The file is in JSON format, but that isn't the problem.

[image: This is the screen shot of the same POST request with postman (chrome tool]

I need to save that 915 code!!

Comment: This code produces a 200 response code? I stripped out the DataOutputStream stuff and it seems to be working for me as long as the url is not redirecting.

Comment: Yes produce 200 code. There is another message that i need to..  But in while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)   in.readLine is null!

Comment: are you sure you are passing correct url, and any headers required (if any)
URL obj = new URL(url);
  HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

Comment: The Url is correct (i've copy and paste from postman). But i see that doesn't send the request, because the 915 code is a progressive code. If i repeat the psot with postman i get the 916 code (so the java post doesn't work). Also if i send the wrong file, i have to get one code.

Comment: Well i also stripped out the socket stuff when i ran the code so maybe the problem in in there. I wonder if you are not authenticated properly if it would still return a 200.

Comment: I'm correctly authenticated, because when i do a GET request at the same URL i can read the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `HttpResponse` and `HttpPost` for getting a response from server (as well as the Response Code):

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpPost(URL));
InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String bufferedStrChunk = null;
while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
}
// now response is in the stringBuilder.toString()
```

I hope this will help you.